# Какой namespace валиден для xml-атрибутов внутри svg?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, анимация, namespace

Задача – начать анимацию `svg` через `js`. Моя (не)реализация – создаём dom-узел с тегом `animate`, ставим необходимые атрибуты, вставляем в конец svg. Проблема – при выполнении

`elem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')`

(а также аналогичной установки любого другого атрибута) я ловлю ошибку:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on
>   'Element': 'www.w3.org/2000/xmlns' is an invalid namespace for
>   attributes.

Если попробовать использовать обычные `.setAttribute()` и `.createElement()`, то анимация просто не работает без каких либо ошибок.

Вопрос: какой `namespace` валиден для `xml`-атрибутов внутри `svg`?

[Посмотреть на ситуацию](https://codepen.io/BanterFace/pen/yKGGJG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `SVG`, как для языка семейства `XML` валидным `namespace` было и остается объявление :

`"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Если вы указали в шапке svg файла эти строки (как в вашем примере), то нет необходимости указывать их в каждой строчке  `JS` для генерации любых элементов `SVG` Проще записать их один раз в переменные и потом многократно использовать

`var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";`

**Создание окружности:**

`var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");`

*создание атрибутов окружности:*

```
 newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",100);
 newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",100);
 newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",20);
```

*Ниже  пример  создания и закраски окружности случайным цветом:*

```
 var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);`
```

**Окружности появляются в случайных местах, случайного размера и цвета после клика**
Полный код скрипта + `SVG`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="400">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    function createCircle() {
      var newCircle = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"circle");
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",Math.random() * 100+250);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",Math.random() * 100+100);      
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"r",Math.random() * 100);       
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke",Math.random() * 100);  
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());      
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newCircle.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementById("firstCircle").appendChild(newCircle);
    }   
     
  ]]></script>
    <g id="firstCircle" onclick="createCircle()"> 
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="30" rx="10" fill="crimson"  />
    <text x="64" y="40" fill="white"  font-size="16px">Create a new circle.</text>
     </g>
</svg>
```

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/geyxoM)

**Работает во всех современных браузерах + IE11**

Comment: Странно, но этот способ [не работает в Mozilla](https://codepen.io/BanterFace/pen/mxgMry) на анимациях. Каких-либо известных багов, связанных с этим, я не обнаружил. Возможно, у создания `animate` есть какие-то особенности?

Comment: @BanterFace загрузил свой пример на Codepen, работает во всех браузерах и даже в IE11 https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/geyxoM

Comment: @BanterFace Если вам обязательно нужно сделать, какую-то свою анимацию средствами JS, то есть прямой смысл обратиться к специализированным библиотекам http://snapsvg.io/  http://svgjs.com/  Эти библиотеки легко осваиваются, имеют хорошую документацию и много примеров

Comment: ваш пример-то работает (как и создание таким же способом других объектов), проблемы именно с анимацией. Не хотел просто подгружать библиотеки для анимации, думал, может это известная проблема. Окей, спасибо.

Comment: @BanterFace Да. вы правы. Лучше сначала разобраться без библиотек. Лучше всего досконально понять как работает **анимация SVG в чистом виде**, а потом уже переводить её в JS, так как это тоже дает плюсы - будет всегда работать везде  и даже в **IE**